# C++ functor (mapping)

Tags: c++, types, metaprogramming, category-theory

I have created a class `either<l, r>` much like Haskell's `Either a b`. I have also implemented a function `map` directly in the class; this is what the code looks like:

```
template<typename l, typename r>
class either 
{
  template<typename b>
  either<l, b> map(const std::function<b (r)> &f)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Now I want to isolate the `map` function in order to create an abstract base class called `functor`

```
template<typename a, template <a> class derived>
class functor
{
public:
  virtual ~functor();

  template<typename b>
  derived<b> map(const std::function<b (a)> &f) = nullptr;
};
```

`either` would inherit this class:

```
class either : functor<r, either<l, r>>
```

however this is invalid C++ as template member functions can not be virtual.

Moreover, I have attempted to test if `<r, either<l, r>>` can match `<a, derived<a>>` in `functor<r, either<l, r>>` (or any other template for that matter) but haven't been able to since it has two template parameters. Also note that other derived classes of functor might have different numbers of template arguments that are irrelevant to functor.

Can the functor base class be expressed in C++ templates?

Comment: I wonder why you want to make it `virtual`. It doesn't achieve anything in your inheritance use case unless you add the ability to inject the class to inherit via a template parameter, at which point you wouldn't need virtual.

Comment: Don't you want something like `template<typename a, typename b, typename C>
typename C::rebind<b>::other map(const std::function<b (a)> &f, const C& c);`

Comment: Imagine for a moment that you managed to make `functor::map` virtual. How exactly do you plan to use it, in a way that requires polymorphism? What do you envision the call site would look like?

Comment: @Igor imagine some generic datastructure D that contains floats (`D<float> instance`) and derives from `functor<float, D<float>>`. Now take a function `std::function<int (float)> discretize`. I want my datastructure to be able to turn from a D<float> to a D<int> by writing `instance.map(discretize);`. Here, it should be infered by the compiler that `b` in the declaration of `map` is an `int` and it should look for definitions of a function `D<float>.map<int>(const std::function<int (float)> &)` in the derived class.

Comment: No part of your scenario requires `map` to be virtual. You are not calling `map` through a pointer or reference to `functor`. I don't see why you need `functor` in the first place.

Comment: That is alright! What if I have a function `template<typename <float> DS> DS<int> discretizeAny(DS<float> &ds) { return ds.map(discretize); }` that discretizes any datastructure that is a functor, whether it's a `D`, a `list`, a `tree` and so on? I am not asking why I would need a functor, I am asking if it is possible to define a class in C++ that guarantees all non-abstract derived classes can be mapped over.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your hypothetical function takes a `DS` as a parameter, not a `functor`. What is the supposed definition of `DS`?

Comment: DS is any derived datastructure from functor (it implements map)

Comment: Why does it need to derive from `functor`, when `discretizeAny` doesn't mention or use `functor` in any shape or form? `discretizeAny` would work quite happily with any class that has a member function named `map`, virtual or otherwise, with a suitable signature. See also [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Comment: Is [this](http://ideone.com/WcMxSf) what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like a stronger guarantee than that the DS class just happens to have a function called `map` with a compatible type signature. Please do note I am asking the question out of genuine interest for the C++ programming language, not because I am on some software development project deadline.

Comment: I don't see how "derived from `functor`" provides any stronger guarantee than "has member function called `map`". What extra guarantees would you like to have, and why would you like to have them?

Comment: A functor has to obey two laws `map id = id` and `map (p . q) = (map p) . (map q)`. Of course it is not realistic to verify whether these laws hold for a derived class in a programming language like C++ so lets ignore that for now. 

It is possible due to programmer error that a non-functor (which just happens to have a function "map") gets passed to a function that relies on the functor laws.  A strongly typed system would warn during compile time that the object passed is not derived from functor. Duck typing would not catch this kind of programming error.

Comment: I'm not sure what `id` and `.` are supposed to stand for. In any case, deriving from `functor` doesn't appear to guarantee any of this. I'm also not sure what you mean by "non-functor (which just happens to have a function `map`)". A class that happens to have a function `map` with suitable signature sounds like a functor to me.

Comment: If you just want your classes marked in a special way, define `struct functor{};`, derive your classes from `functor`, and in `discretizeAll` write `static_assert(is_base_of<functor, decltype(ds)>::value, "must derive from functor");`

Comment: @Maarten: The normal way to provide this guarantee is NOT inheritance, that's the Java way.  In C++ we use tag dispatching: `template<class T> struct is_map_functor: std::false_type {};  template<> struct is_map_functor<discretizeAny>: std::true_type {};`  See also: `std::is_fundamental` and `std::is_integral` and the thousands like them.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_fundamental/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the curiously recurring template pattern, there's no need for virtual functions. Your goal of **dispatching to the method of the derived class** can be achieved directly from the base class.

A typical [**implementation**](http://ideone.com/KPqvDP) would be the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename a, class derived>
class functor
{
public:
    // You have to define the destructor
    virtual ~functor() {}

    template<typename b>
    // The full type of the derived class is known
    derived map(const std::function<b(a)> &f)
    {
        // Here you take advantage of the CRTP
        return static_cast<derived*>(this)->map(f);
    }
};

template<typename l, typename r>
// You have to put public as inheritance access level
class either : public functor<r, either<l, r>>
{ // The way you want to inherit implies that the base has no 
  // template template parameter, just template parameters !!
public:
    template<typename b>
    either<l, b> map(const std::function<b(r)> &f)
    {
        cout << "In derived" << endl;
        return  either<l, b>();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // pointer to base class points to a derived object
    functor<int, either<int, int>> *ff = new either<int, int>();
    // map function will call the method of the derived class
    ff->map<int>([](int k){ return 1; });

    return 0;
}
```

I took the liberty of pointing some things out in the comments. HTH